# How to craft an XSLT if query for multiple attributes of an item

Tags: xml, xslt

We have an application that outputs a XML file so big I haven't yet found an editor to open it properly. This file is no use to anyone but the application does provide an option to upload a XSLT file to filter the output, turn it into a CSV, and therefore making it usable.

My XSLT knowledge is limited (all derived from MDN, YouTube and here), and I need to change an existing file to meet new requirements...

The XML has formatting is like so - there are a lot more fields but these are pertinent to my question (most field names and details changed to keep me out of trouble):

```
<applicationNameSkillsExtract xmlns="http://www.vendorwebsite.co.uk/applicationNameSkillsExtract/1.6"
    xmlns:cc="http://www.vendorwebsite.co.uk/applicationNameCore/1.8">
    <allHumans>
        <cc:human applicationID="user1" archived="false">
            <cc:employeeID>1111</cc:employeeID>
            <cc:firstName>Jane</cc:firstName>
            <cc:surname>Doe</cc:surname>
            <cc:company>Acme</cc:company>
        </cc:human>
        <cc:human applicationID="user2" archived="false">
            <cc:employeeID>2222</cc:employeeID>
            <cc:firstName>John</cc:firstName>
            <cc:surname>Smith</cc:surname>
            <cc:company>Acme Subsidiary</cc:company>
        </cc:human>
    </allHumans>
    <allSkills>
        <cc:skill skillID="skill1" type="Basic">
            <cc:name>Introduction to Acme Corporation</cc:name>
        </cc:skill>
        <cc:skill skillID="skill2" type="Intermediate">
            <cc:name>How to be a manager</cc:name>
        </cc:skill>
        <cc:skill skillID="skill3" type="Basic">
            <cc:name>Making coffee</cc:name>
        </cc:skill>
        <cc:skill skillID="skill4" type="Intermediate">
            <cc:name>Making proper coffee</cc:name>
        </cc:skill>
    </allSkills>
    <allExpertises>
        <cc:expertise applicationID="skill1" expertiseID="expertise1" type="JobRole1">
            <cc:name>OK to make the boss coffee</cc:name>
            <cc:skill ref="skill1"/>
            <cc:skill ref="skill3"/>
            <cc:skill ref="skill4"/>
        </cc:expertise>
        <cc:expertise applicationID="skill2" expertiseID="expertise2" type="JobRole2">
            <cc:name>OK to make everyone else coffee</cc:name>
            <cc:skill ref="skill1"/>
            <cc:skill ref="skill3"/>
        </cc:expertise>
    </allExpertises>
    <roleSkillStatus>
        <cc:humanExpertiseStatus expertiseRef="expertise1" humanRef="user2">
            <cc:currentlyAuthorised>false</cc:currentlyAuthorised>
        </cc:humanExpertiseStatus>
        <cc:humanExpertiseStatus expertiseRef="expertise2" humanRef="user2">
            <cc:currentlyAuthorised>false</cc:currentlyAuthorised>
        </cc:humanExpertiseStatus>
        <cc:humanExpertiseStatus expertiseRef="expertise1" humanRef="user1">
            <cc:currentlyAuthorised>true</cc:currentlyAuthorised>
        </cc:humanExpertiseStatus>
    </roleSkillStatus>
</applicationNameSkillsExtract>
```

The XSLT I am working from creates a CSV header row, and then within a `xsl:for-each` loop it pulls out certain attributes and places them into the CSV, but only if a `xsl:when test` clause is satisfied. This clause checks the employeeID field for the humans starts with a specific digit. This all works fine.

The new requirement is to add an additional check to only extract data from roleSkillStatus if the expertiseRef is of type JobRole1 and currentlyAuthorised. In the above example, expertise1 for user2 would not be added as while the expertise is of the correct type, it is not currently authorised. However, expertise1 for user1 would be valid.

I was thinking of the following XSLT but it fails to extract anything:

```
<xsl:variable name="varHumanRef" select="@humanRef"/>
<xsl:variable name="varExportSkillFA" select="/cse:applicationNameSkillsExtract/cse:allExpertises/cc:expertise[@type='JobRole1']" />

<xsl:for-each select="//cc:humanExpertiseStatus">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="(starts-with(/cse:applicationNameSkillsExtract/cse:allHumans/cc:human[@applicationID=$varHumanRef]/cc:employeeNumber,'07'))">
            <xsl:if test="/cse:applicationNameSkillsExtract/cse:roleSkillStatuses/cc:humanExpertiseStatus[@expertiseRef=$varExportSkillFA][@humanRef=$varhumanRef]/cc:currentlyAuthorised='true'">
```

I've tried many many variants of the above but not got anywhere. There are probably many issues with it, but I think it's likely down to how I am testing for both @expertiseRef and @humanRef. Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's quite hard to see how this all comes together. What is the context when you run that code snippet you posted? In your first test you are in the context of a cc:humanExpertiseStatus, which only contains a cc:currentlyAuthorised but you try to select a cse:applicationNameSkillsExtract?  Maybe try your basic example there : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMow and rethink your question a bit so it's easier to follow?

Comment: Please, for the next time: Post an XML file that *works*. It's super annoying to have to manually sort out avoidable errors in the XML structure just to be able to get a grip of the problem.

Comment: ...apart from that, it's entirely unclear what your output is supposed to look like, and the situation is too complex to guess.

Comment: @Tomalak - can you point towards a part of the XML doesn't work as this will help me in my discussions with the application vendor? The XML above is as extracted by the application with some basic Find & Replace to change sensitive fields.

Comment: @Sebastien - thanks for the URL, I've been looking for something like this but was starting think it didn't exist. Really helpful, thanks.

Comment: @AndrewC I've already fixed it. Look at the edit I made on your question, you'll see the differences. Your find-and-replace changes broke the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:cse="http://www.vendorwebsite.co.uk/applicationNameSkillsExtract/1.6"
    xmlns:cc="http://www.vendorwebsite.co.uk/applicationNameCore/1.8"
>
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:key name="kValidHumanExpertise" match="cc:humanExpertiseStatus[
        cc:currentlyAuthorised = 'true'
    ]" use="@humanRef" />
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//cc:human" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="cc:human">
        <xsl:value-of select="cc:employeeID" />
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="cc:firstName" />
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="cc:surname" />
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="cc:company" />
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        
        <!-- extract relevant <cc:expertise> -->
        <xsl:for-each select="
            //cc:expertise[
                @expertiseID = key('kValidHumanExpertise', current()/@applicationID)/@expertiseRef
                and @type  = 'JobRole1'
            ]
        ">
            <xsl:value-of select="cc:name" />
            <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>

        <!-- extract relevant <cc:skill> -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//cc:skill[
            @skillID = //cc:expertise[
                @expertiseID = key('kValidHumanExpertise', current()/@applicationID)/@expertiseRef
            ]/cc:skill/@ref
        ]">
            <xsl:value-of select="cc:name" />
            <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces

```
1111;Jane;Doe;Acme;OK to make the boss coffee;Introduction to Acme Corporation|Making coffee|Making proper coffee
2222;John;Smith;Acme Subsidiary;;
```

Here the columns are `employeeID`, `firstName`, `surname`, `company`, `expertise names`, and `skill names`, with the last two columns being multi-valued. Main delimiter is `;`, field-internal delimiter is `|`.

The `expertise names` column is to fulfill the requirement

> extract data from `roleSkillStatus` if the `expertiseRef` is of type `JobRole1` and `currentlyAuthorised`

and the `skill names` column is to demonstrate how to take this a step further and reference more data from the document.

---

A more efficient version of the above would require two additional `<xsl:key>` declarations:

```
<xsl:key name="kExpertiseById" match="cc:expertise" use="@expertiseID" />
<xsl:key name="kSkillById" match="cc:skill" use="@skillID" />
```

and then we could replace all the `//cc:expertise` and `//cc:skill` with key look-ups:

```
<xsl:for-each select="
    key(
        'kExpertiseById', 
        key('kValidHumanExpertise', @applicationID)/@expertiseRef
    )[@type  = 'JobRole1']
">
    <!-- ... -->
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="
    key(
        'kSkillById',
        key(
            'kExpertiseById', 
            key('kValidHumanExpertise', @applicationID)/@expertiseRef
        )[@type  = 'JobRole1']/cc:skill/@ref
    )
">
    <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: Hi @Tomalak, That is really helpful, thank you. I appreciate your time to fix my XML, understand my question and work out an answer. I've been working on this throughout the day and in the last hour I got something working using nested for loops - but it is very inefficient, takes over double the time to run. I'm going to spend the evening working through your answer to understand it better and make use of it - the explanations look very helpful. Thank you

Comment: @AndrewC Thanks for the feedback! I've not explained everything I used, if you stumble across something that just refuses to reveal itself to you, ask away.